# Google Spreadsheet QUERY function and pivoting

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So I have a table in Google Spreadsheets such as

```
Header A | Value A1 | Value A2 | Value A3
Header B | Value B1 | Value B2 | Value B3
Header C | Value C1 | Value C2 | Value C3
```

But I want the result

```
Header A | Header B | Header C
Value A1 | Value B1 | Value C1
Value A2 | Value B2 | Value C2
Value A3 | Value B3 | Value C3
```

How can I easily achieve this with a =QUERY()? I am not finding any good resources on understanding pivot. If someone can explain or supply a link, I am guessing this is an argument I want to use in QUERY to do this.

Comment: Found TRANSPOSE function..

Comment: Sorry, I initially deleted my answer because I wasn't certain if you were interested in learning more about =QUERY() or if you just wanted the table transposed.

Comment: I was thinking this was done via Query but it was my rookie mistake. I found out about the Transpose function soon after I posted this. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=TRANSPOSE()` formula should give you the desired output if I'm understanding you correctly.